# Project Module: Filtering Data in Crystal Reports? (by day, month, year)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, ms-access-2010, oledb

I need to show only 1 report per month (`cboMonth`) of the sales earned everyday during the month, and by what year (`cboYear`) was that month.

As shown, I already have a command that summarizes the sales earned in all shifts in a day. But the problem is, I don't know how to filter `TPrice` by month (maybe through `cboMonth`) so it will **display only what has been earned during a month**.

I don't know how to search the web for this but all my knowledge is just self-taught from free videos and I haven't covered data filtering by dates.

Update: I have tried this, but now I get an error.

I just need to know how to **filter all my data in my report by month** and it would really help me a lot.

[image]

Comment: You should be using a record-selection formula.

Comment: Can you give me an easy instruction for this? :(

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Create a formula `@Month Grouping` and write below code:

```
Month(Created_Date);
```

Now create the group using this formula.

Edit...........

you are doing wrong use the formula `@Month Grouping` in `Insert Group` window not in the `Use Formula as Group Sort Order` that is wrong hence you are getting that error.

To create a formula go to Desing and to the right side there will be field explorer there on formula filed right click and click `new` a window is opened there write the code.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But in what window exactly could I find this? Anyway I'll try to look for it.

Comment: I think I get it. I'm under the "Group" menu now.

Comment: @NewbieJason there is a option `Insert Group`.. click on that and select the created formula so that grouping is done

Comment: thanks for the tip, although I hope you could help me with the error it shows. Updated post. :(

Comment: Can you post formula along with the commnets?

Comment: your formula `Month(Created_Date)` has the opening and closing braces I guess there may be something along with this code that doesn't have the closing braces

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Sorry it's taking too long. I have updated the post. Can you help me out just a little bit more? Am I doing it right? Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Remove `@` before month and inside braces give a valid date

Comment: Updated. I've also tried (08/08/08) but says "date must be inserted here". I guess I've set something wrong with the development before and just need further researching. Thank you very much for your effort and sorry for any obvious mistakes. @Siva

Comment: Np you are welcome instead of (08/08/08) try Cdate ("08/08/08")